# Filling in a 4D matrix with 2d matrixes

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering if there was a numpy function that would make this faster. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
def _sparse_4D_rand_mat(self, x, y, density):
    _4D_mat = np.empty((x, y, x, y))
    for i in range(self.size):
        for j in range(self.size):
            _4D_mat[:,i,j,:] = self._rand_sparse(x, y, density)
    return _4D_mat
def _rand_sparse(self, m, n, density, format='csr'):
    nnz = max(min(int(m * n * density), m * n), 0)
    row = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=m - 1, size=nnz)
    col = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=n - 1, size=nnz)
    data = np.ones(nnz, dtype=float)
    data = np.random.dirichlet(data)
    return csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(m, n)).toarray()
```

Thank you for your contribution.
I'm new ;)

Comment: What's the datatype of `self._rand_sparse` and `_4D_mat`?

Comment: both are numpy.matrix

Comment: Oh  wait `_rand_sparse` looks like a function. So, to make it faster, it would make more sense to see its implementation.

Comment: http://pyamg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyamg/gallery/random_sparse.html

The first function

Comment: Does the density change for each `(i, j)`?

Comment: x, y, density all stay the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the density remains constant, instead of calling `_rand_sparse` multiple times to generate many small sparse 2D arrays, you could call `_rand_sparse` once to generate one big sparse 2D array, and then use the `reshape` method to reshape the 2D result as a 4D array:

```
_4D_mat = _rand_sparse(x * y * x, y, density)
_4D_mat = _4D_mat.reshape((x, y, x, y))
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse

def _rand_sparse(m, n, density, format='csr'):
    nnz = max(min(int(m * n * density), m * n), 0)
    # use randint since random_integer is deprecated in NumPy 1.11.0
    row = np.random.randint(low=0, high=m, size=nnz)
    col = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n, size=nnz)
    data = np.ones(nnz, dtype=float)
    data = np.random.dirichlet(data)
    return sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(m, n)).toarray()

def orig(x, y, density):
    _4D_mat = np.empty((x, y, x, y))
    for i in range(y):
        for j in range(x):
            _4D_mat[:, i, j, :] = _rand_sparse(x, y, density)
    return _4D_mat

def alt(x, y, density):
    _4D_mat = _rand_sparse(x * y * x, y, density)
    _4D_mat = _4D_mat.reshape((x, y, x, y))
    return _4D_mat

x, y, density = 2, 4, 0.5
```

Since `alt` eliminates the double for-loop, this solution will be much much faster than `orig` as the value of `x` and `y` grows large (that is, as the number of iterations in the for-loops grows). In fact, even for small values such as those used above, `alt` is already (almost 8x) faster than `orig`:

```
In [108]: %timeit orig(x, y, density)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.24 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit alt(x, y, density)
1000 loops, best of 3: 281 µs per loop
```

---

> I need the sum for each 2D array in the 4D array to be 1

To normalize the appropriate slices you could use:

```
totals = np.nansum(_4D_mat, axis=0, keepdims=True)
totals = np.nansum(totals, axis=3, keepdims=True)
_4D_mat /= totals
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I need the sum for each 2D array in the 4D array to be 1.